# Identities using only binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, universal-algebra

There are many known combinatorial identities involving the binomial coefficient, although essentially all of the well known ones involve some function or constant other than the binomial coefficient itself.

For example, Pascal's identity ${n\choose k} = {n-1\choose k-1} + {n-1 \choose k}$ makes use of subtraction, addition, and the constant $1$.

The identities ${n\choose 0} = 1$ and ${n\choose 1} = n$ use the constants $0$ and $1$.

I am interested in identities which use **only** variables and the binomial coefficient (in the same way that the associative and commutative laws for multiplication use only variables, multiplication and no other functions).

Notice, for example, that we have the identity ${a\choose a}=1$, which allows us to write the last of the above identities as $${n\choose {a\choose a}} = n$$

Furthermore, since $1=1$ we have the identity $${a\choose a} = {b\choose b}$$

These two identities are built out of only variable and binomial coefficients. Do there exist any other such identities, which don't follow logically from these two above?

In the language of universal algebra, is the smallest variety $V$ containing $\langle\mathbb{N}, B\rangle$ (where $B$ is the 2-ary binomial coefficient function) exactly the class of algebraic structures whose signature is a single 2-ary function $B$ satisfying the identities $B(n,B(a,a)) = n$ and $B(a,a) = B(b,b)$?

If not, how can one describe this variety $V$?

(Note: I take the convention that if $a < b$, then ${a\choose b}=0$)

Comment: I have little experience with universal algebra so let me know if I didn't phrase my question above correctly in the language of universal algebra.

Comment: Your identities don't characterise $B$. You could require $B(m, m) = 1$ and $B(m, 1) = m$  for all $m$ and then take $B(n, m)$ to be anything you like when $n \neq m$ and $m \neq 1$. The phrasing of your question makes sense in universal algebra terms, but I wouldn't expect to be able to characterise $B$ without introducing other operators. For a simpler example, think about addition.

Comment: @RobArthan I agree that my identities certainly don't characterize B, although characterizing B is not the intent of my question (apologies if I phrased it badly). What I want to characterize is the collection of identities which hold for the binomial coefficient B, and I wonder if my two identities along with their logical consequences characterize those. For example, is there an identity which holds for the binomial coefficient B but not for some B chosen as you indicated?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. An interesting question. Again I would encourage you to think about simpler examples like addition first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**is the smallest variety $V$ containing $\langle\mathbb{N}, B\rangle$ (where $B$ is the 2-ary binomial coefficient function) exactly the class of algebraic structures whose signature is a single 2-ary function $B$ satisfying the identities $B(n,B(a,a)) = n$ and $B(a,a) = B(b,b)$?**

No.

Your algebra $\langle\mathbb{N}, B\rangle$ satisfies the identity

$$B(B(x,x),B(B(y,y),z)) = B(w,w)$$

but this identity is not a consequence of the two identities you identified. To see that it is not a consequence, note that the algebra $\mathbb Z_2 = \langle \{0,1\}; B(x,y)\rangle$ with $B(x,y) = x+y\pmod{2}$ satisfies your two identities, but does not satisfy the more complicated identity I wrote.

---

Let me mention an interesting and less obvious identity satisfied by the variety $V=V(\mathbf{A})$ that is generated by the binomial algebra $\mathbf{A}:=\langle\mathbb{N}, B\rangle$. (I refer to the identity $p(x,x,z)=q(x,z,z)$ below.) Define terms

$p(x,y,z) = B(B(x,B(y,z)),B(z,y))$

$q(x,y,z) = B(B(z,B(x,y)),B(y,x))$.

It is not too hard to verify that the following identities hold in $\mathbf{A}$ (hence in $V$):

$$p(x,z,z)=x, \quad p(x,x,z)=q(x,z,z), \quad q(x,x,z) = z.$$

These are 'Hagemann-Mitschke identities for $3$-permutability'. These identities imply that, for any two congruences $\alpha, \beta$ on any algebra $\mathbf{B}\in V$ it is the case that $\alpha\circ\beta\circ\alpha = \beta\circ\alpha\circ\beta$. In particular, the existence of HM terms for $3$-permutability implies that $V$ is a congruence modular variety. The first and last of these HM identities follow from your two identities, but the middle one, $p(x,x,z)=q(x,z,z)$, does not follow since $\mathbb Z_2 = \langle \{0,1\}; B(x,y)\rangle$ with $B(x,y)=x+y\pmod{2}$ does not satisfy the middle HM identity.

It is possible to strengthen the conclusion that $V(\mathbf{A})$ to congruence modular to the conclusion that $V(\mathbf{A})$ to congruence distributive, as follows. First, let $x*z$ denote $p(x,x,z) = B(B(x,B(x,z)),B(z,x))$. Then let $x\vee z = (x*z)*(z*x)$. The operation $x\vee z$ is a semilattice operation on $\mathbf{A}$, namely it is the join operation for the semilattice order where $0, 2, 3, 4, \ldots$ are pairwise incomparable and the join of any two of them is $1$. Now, any congruence modular variety which has a semilattice term is congruence distributive.